# How to repeat same query for multiple values in Grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Using Grafana and an InfluxDB database, I build a panel with this query:

```
SELECT "ZoomRendered01" FROM "exec" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

I should repeat this same query for those fields:

- `ZoomRendered02`:

  `SELECT "ZoomRendered02" FROM "exec" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)`
- `ZoomRendered03`

  `SELECT "ZoomRendered03" FROM "exec" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)`
- `ZoomRendered04`

  `SELECT "ZoomRendered04" FROM "exec" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)`
- ...
- until `ZoomRendered20`

Is there a way to ask Grafana to repeat those queries **on the same panel** for all those fields automatically ?

**Edit**: adding precision: the repeated queries should be shown on the same panel.

Comment: Can you add an explanation why `select zoom01, zoom02, zomm03 ....` is not an acceptable approach?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use Grafana templating:

- define custom variable, for example `fieldName` with multiple values: *ZoomRendered01*,*ZoomRendered02*,*ZoomRendered03*,...
- set `multi-value` option for this variable
- use this variable in query: `SELECT "$fieldName" FROM "exec" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)`
- turn on `Repeating` for all values of $fieldName in `General` section of panel editor.

These steps should produce multiple panels on dashboard (one for each of $fieldName values).

Comment: If the `ZoomRenderednn` values at the first step are fields of a measurement you can also run a query on that measurement that dynamically returns the values you need.

Comment: It works great, but this create multiple panels. I would like to see the data in the same panels, creating multiple queries. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: If `ZoomRenderedNN` fields are the only fields in measurement, then `SELECT * FROM "exec" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)` should do what you want. Otherwise you'd have to change data scheme: use measurement with `value` field and add `ZoomRendered` tag with tag values `ZoomeRendered01`,`ZoemRendered02`,...

Answer (score -1):

influxdb accepts regular expressions for field name matching in a query:

```
SELECT /^ZoomRendered(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)$/ FROM "exec" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

Or if you really just want all fields from "exec" then you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM "exec" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? From what I read in the [InfluxQL documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#regular-expressions) this answer looks fine for me.

Comment: @SaschaDoerdelmann, I guess this answer donvoted because of it missing the point. OP can manually list fields, without any regex. But question is about how to repeat similar query multiple times

Comment: I still don't get the point: The question clearly states "the repeated queries should be shown on the same panel". Template variables will get you multiple panels on the same dashboard.

Comment: Yes indeed, my original suggestion will show the results for all of those fields on the same panel. The underlying answer here is that you don't really need multiple queries to get results for multiple fields, just a more complex single query.